# Sanitizing UTF-8 encoded strings

Tags: python, mysql, sanitization

I want to sanitise a UTF-8 encoded string before using it as part of a MySQL SELECT statement.

For example, I have:

```
query = MySQLdb.escape_string(query)
```

but this line is leading to a raised exception that reads

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in
>   range(128).

How can I handle this?

Comment: Clearly something is assuming your string is in US-ASCII and not UTF-8.  I would try explicitly encoding it with something like `query.encode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like MySQLdb is trying to encode your unicode query to a string. To do so it's using the default encoding: ASCII.

Now, your input can't be encoded into ASCII, so you just need to tell python what encoding it should use: utf-8.

You can achieve this by using `query = query.encode('utf-8').`

Comment: Exactly my problem. I have to jump in and out of UTF-8 encodings, to keep MySQL happy to and to keep everyone else happy.

Comment: This unfortunately happens all the time, with many modules, whenever you use non-ASCII unicode strings that python can't handle on its own. For your MySQLdb problem, you might want to look into an ORM layer, such as SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 3):

In your example `query` is of type 'str'.  If you put a 'u' before the string, it becomes of type 'unicode'.

```
>>> query = "こうえん"
>>> print type(query)
<type 'str'>
>>> query = u"こうえん"
>>> print type(query)
<type 'unicode'>
```

This is one of the main differences between Python versions 2.x and 3.x.  Starting in 3.0, all strings are 'unicode' by default.

Comment: *Note:* I don't think I have that module installed, but this is a general solution to a general problem.  I hope it works, but if it doesn't @Ada's code probably will (or a combination of the two).

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.6. I've removed "こうえん" from the question because it doesn't help.

Comment: Do I need to set some global character set for MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
query = "こうえん"
query = MySQLdb.escape_string(unicode(query,'utf-8'))
```

Comment: This gives "Exception Value:decoding Unicode is not supported". I'm using Python 2.6.6. I've removed "こうえん" from the question because it doesn't help.

Comment: Do I need to set some global character set for MySQL?

Comment: Which function is giving the error?  Try separating the two functions, i.e., `query = unicode(query,'utf-8')` and then pass `query` to the escape function.  Which line is the error on?

Comment: [Works on my machine!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html)

Comment: The `decoding Unicode is not supported` error means that the string is already Unicode. Meaning this is not the issue!